# Three div's in two columns - equal height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need the following Layout:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|           |           |
|   Div A   |           |
|           |           |
|           |           |
+-----------+   Div C   |
|           |           |
|    Div B  |           |
|           |           |
|           |           |
+-----------+-----------+
```

The boxes should be responsive and contain images (one for each box).

I am using bootstrap 3 and found a possible solution, unfortunately the heights depend also on the image size. I can't use tables and the layout has to be responsive, so a fixed height is no solution. I searched trough stackoverflow but I could not find a solution.

One approach is this (which is working well in the fiddle, except the images:

```js
var colHeight = $(".slider").height();
var colHeight2 = colHeight - 30;
$('.child').css('min-height', colHeight2 / 2);
```

```css
.slider {
  background: #555;
}
.image1 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: #555;
}
.image2 {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 slider">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/700x600" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 image1 child">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 image2 child" style="overflow: hidden;">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I`ve created a fiddle here:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bq2jx0co/2/)

Comment: Maybe flexbox with a float fallback for IE9?

Answer (score 0):

You could check display:flex. I would do the below:

```
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="inner-container item">
        <div>
            <img src="" style="height:300px"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="" style="height:200px"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="" />
    </div>
</div>
.outer-container {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .outer-container, .inner-container {
        display: flex;
    }
    .inner-container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    div {
        border: 1px solid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your jsfiddle

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6" >
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6" >

  <img src="http://placehold.it/700x600" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign

```
display:flex;
```

To all the child div's in the row class.

example here http://codepen.io/tom-maton/pen/Ywdzeo

Comment: Nice approach, but the images get out of proportion on resizing. I'll fiddle a bit with this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="row">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" class="img-responsive"/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" class="img-responsive"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" style="height:600px" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want to same display on mobile view,you can use table.
as i know, bootstrap smaller col is col-xs, you can add it after col-sm-6.
ex: class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"